# Manifest file issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

well i have a small app that i am building. so i have 10 activity and inside one of them i have 6 TextView that are gonna open another activity and when i try to come back to the subactivity of the main activity i dont have the back arow. so i want to put them the back arrow. i gave  this where im having issue with.
here is my manifest.xlm file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CenturyActivity"
        android:label="Centure Auto Parts"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".AlshamaliActivity"
        android:label="Al Shamali Auto Parts"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".IndusActivity"
        android:label="Indus Auto Parts"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MayadActivity"
        android:label="Al Mayad Auto Parts"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ImparialActivity"
        android:label="Imperial Auto Parts"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".AisinActivity"
        android:label="AISIN Gallery Auto Parts"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SpdcActivity"
        android:label="SPDC Warehouse"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ImwhouseActivity"
        android:label="Imperial Warehouse"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".WshamaliActivity"
        android:label="Al Shamali Warehouse"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />

    **<activity**
        android:name=".HeadOfficeActivity"
        android:label="Head Office"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HrActivity"
        android:label="HR Team"
        android:parentActivityName=".HeadOfficeActivity"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HeadOfficeActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".SalesActivity"
        android:label="Sales Team"
        android:parentActivityName=".HeadOfficeActivity"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".HeadOfficeActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".PurchActivity"
        android:label="Purchase Team"
        android:parentActivityName=".HeadOfficeActivity"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".HeadOfficeActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".AccountsActivity"
        android:label="Accounts Team"
        android:parentActivityName=".HeadOfficeActivity"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".HeadOfficeActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ItActivity"
        android:label="IT Team"
        android:parentActivityName=".HeadOfficeActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".HeadOfficeActivity"/>
</activity>
</application>
```

Comment: this is the error i get every time i ran the app
"Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

Comment: Once remove all meta-data tags and android:parentActivityName and check. Thank  you

Comment: Issue have been solved.. thanks